# Spark config to tune a job doing left join

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, left-join

There is a use case in which we have 160 gb source dataframe repartitioned into 100 based on the column which is used for doing a left join with a smaller lookup having 30-40 gb data size. Post that the same source dataframe with this new column added is then sequentially left joined with 50 more smaller lookup tables having size of 30-40 gbs for which these lookup tables are cached, and joined to add 50 more new columns to existing source df, but this time with no repartitioning.

The configs being used are
30g exe memory
4 cores
50 num-executors.

Questions:

1. What is the value of spark.sql.shuffle.partitions
2. Any other tuning which we can use at spark config level to tune the job.